# How to build iOS app for Seetest

Tags: automated-testing, continuous-integration, seetest

I am trying to find out how to build (compile, prepare, process ...) an app for Seetest, so that it can be tested on devices without adding them to the Apple Developer Portal.

I know how to build an app that will be run on registered devices, but Seetest also claims to support unregistered devices.

Please provide some steps or a proper documentation,
Tx!

Comment: I think with a iOS 6 device you can use the app without a developer profile. You just need iOSBridge installed on the device. For higher versions it is needed and can not be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seetest provides a certificate in a custom format that can be applied with the Seetest application. Prior to that, you have to provide them the device UDID, so it looks like they register that in one of their Apple Dev accounts.

There is no special setup required, this works with Apps originally signed with an Enterprise account or a normal Dev account. For example the builds you put on TestFlight work fine.